# Using max/min functions to remember highs/lows in dynamic data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dynamic data shown in Excel. The data itself is pulled using COM from external application, and it is basically number changing over time (for example, outside temperature which is received from weather website).

Is there some convenient way to store MIN/MAX() of value observed during some period *without* use of VBA and macroses? Using simple formula in `max_cell` like `=IF(data_cell>max_cell, data_cell, max_cell)` gives circular reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn Iteration on then the circular reference will work ok on a continuous basis

And rather than an IF you can just use in A1 (where A1 is max_cell, A2 data_cell)

`=MAX(A1,A2)`

*Enabling Iteration*

- In Excel 2003, From the Tools menu, select Options. 2. In the Calculation tab, select the Iteration checkbox and click OK.
- [Iteration xl2007](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/avoiding-circular-references-in-excel-2007-formula.html)
- [Iteration xl2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700515.aspx#Office2007excelPerf_ControllingCalculationOptions)

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate you asked for a non VBA solution but I will offer one as it is quite trivial to implement and understand. I'll leave it up to you whether you want to use it or not.

Suppose your data is organised as follows in `Sheet1` of your workbook:

```
    A    B    C
1   Temp Max  Min
2   25   32   14
```

The following code will update `Max` and `Min` whenever `Temp` changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim temp As Range, max As Range, min As Range

    Set temp = Range("A2") //Change for your specific set-up
    Set max = Range("B2")  //Change for your specific set-up
    Set min = Range("C2")  //Change for your specific set-up

    If Not Intersect(temp, Target) Is Nothing Then
        max = WorksheetFunction.max(Target, max)
        min = WorksheetFunction.min(Target, min)
    End If
End Sub
```

For clarity, to add this code from worksheet:

1. Open VB Editor (**ALT + F11**)
2. In **Project Explorer** double click **Sheet1**
3. Select `Worksheet` in left hand drop down menu and then `Change` in right hand drop down